# Problem with todonotes - "Unknown option 'textsize' "

Tags: fontsize, todonotes

I'm writing a document with `a5paper` formatting (obtained through the [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package). In particular this means that I have narrower margins.

I really like TikZ and especially [`todonotes`](http://ctan.org/pkg/todonotes). The problem is that the box is larger than the margin. To fix that, I used the option `textwidth`, and all went fine.

As a last thing, I'd like to be able to reduce the size of the text, so I can fit larger words in.  The option `textsize` seems to be there just for this purpose: unfortunately it doesn't work for me.

Here is an example of code I tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[textsize=tiny]{todonotes}
\begin{document}
  blah blah blah blah\todo{more grothendieck blah} whatever blah blah.
\end{document}
```

obtaining the following in the log file

```
/usr/local/texlive/2008/texmf-dist/tex/latex/todonotes/todonotes.sty:80: LaTeX 
Error: Unknown option `textsize' for package `todonotes'
```

I also tried to download the package from CTAN and to load it locally but I got the same message.

Am I doing something wrong? Should I be perhaps updating TeXlive or something?

Comment: Your example works fine for me, with MikTeX 2.9 (beta), so yes, try updating TeXLive.

Comment: According to the documentation `textsize` was added with version 0.7.6 of todonotes

Comment: @Torbjorn: Could you please post that as an answer, so that it can be accepted. (Works fine with TeX Live 2009 and 2010.)

Comment: I can't believe I still have texlive 2008! I'll proceed with an update immediately.

Comment: @slackerny, I am not sure if I'm right, but I think it would be better to write more informative titles when posting a question, for example: 'Problem with the textsize option in todonotes' or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example works fine with MikTeX 2.9 beta and TeXLive 2009/2010 (ref. Caramdirs comment),
so an update of TeXLive should do the trick.

Comment: Maybe redundant but let me add that I tried it with TexLive 2011 (on Ubuntu 11.10) and it also works.

Answer (score 5):

From reading the documentation, it looks like you want to use the option `[size=\tiny]`.

Comment: Sure, but doesn't this work just for the single \todo command and not globally as an option for the whole package? I guess I could always write a \newcommand to include that option. It's just a shame that this textsize doesn't work.

Comment: @slackenerny: Ah yes, you are correct.

Comment: @TH: anyway, I appreciated the RTFM answer, I should be doing it more often.

Comment: @slackenerny: And I should have read it more carefully. =)